# Semicolons in PHP form submissions

Tags: php, mysql

Two related questions that should be easy, though my searching has come up empty.

1. I have a from in PHP.  If a field has a semi-colon in it, and I do a dump of $_POST in the action page, the field value is truncated at the semi-colon.  I'm guessing this is related to SQL injection security?  But legitimate semi-colons need to be allowed.  Is there a setting that allows this to go through?  Or do I need to escape it, and if so, how?
2. To catch actual SQL injections, I don't need to allow multiple statements in one query... like "SELECT * FROM table;DROP table".  Is there a setting that disables this, either in PHP or MySQL, but without stopping legitimate semicolons?

Comment: I've never heard of semicolons being a problem. Can you show an example of what you're inputting?

Comment: Also, you don't need to detect SQL injections, you need to make all input benign.

Comment: I don't have an answer for question 1 yet, but as for 2, what you can do is use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

semi-colons does not cause any problem.

Use prepared statements.

In [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

In [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"];
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $safe_variable . "')");
```

Check this question for more information [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1868660)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly me.  Yes, I am using prepared statements, escaping, etc.  But I also wanted to sanitize the input before it even gets that far.  So I have a global function that checks all parameters, taking out anything following apostrophes and semicolons.  Works fine for GET values, but I forgot that I needed to update that to handle POST parameters differently, and had forgotten this was there, as I hadn't type a semi-colon until now. :)  But thanks for the responses.